# Secondary display does not show complete screen

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have Ubuntu 14.04, and am seeing an issue with my secondary display.

For some reason, it seems that on all 4 sides of the display, there are regions I cannot see. The picture stretches the entire screen but it's like it's zoomed into the center a bit, and I lose about the height of a title bar.

If I maximize something on the screen, it will maximize into these regions, so that, for instance, the top title bar of the window will be hidden from me.

I tried taking a screenshot for this issue, but it shows nothing out of the ordinary. So to demonstrate, I decided to manually resize my browser window (right side) to the corners of my visibility. Any further and I cannot see it.

The monitor in question is connected via HDMI if that makes any difference.

Oh, and I primarily use GNOME, but I see the same issue in Unity and GNOME2.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Settyngs : Hardware : Display, and select the screen which is you need to turn it off.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I'm not looking to turn it off, I just need the sides to display on the screen so I can use it properly

Comment: Fine, Then please check "Show displays in panel" has enabled and resolution has set to correct ratio for both the display, Choosing "Show displays in panel" will display the icon to configure the display on the top right hand panel for easy access, simply drag them to rearrange them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the resolution isn't correct for that monitor, if you try changing resolution in the Display settings mentioned earlier does that do anything?

(Or `xrandr` has more options for changing the displays, maybe something in there would help)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a TV connected via HDMI, it may be that the “zoom/aspect-ratio” setting is wrong or that the TV just doesn't support “dot for dot” input, which is often the case with TVs more than a few years old.

My current TV has a button on the remote that you push to switch from 16:9 (“Full”) to 4:5 (“Normal”); it also has two zoom levels and “PC Mode” that makes the TV behave like a 1920x1080 monitor.

However, my previous TV had no such “PC Mode” and the top 20 pixels or so of the computer display would be off-screen on the TV no matter what setting I used, just enough that I could only see one or two pixels of the bottom of the menu bar. If you had a DVD player connected via HDMI, you'd never notice the little bit missing from video playback, but for a computer desktop display it is essential that you see every pixel.